# How can I process a text file as input in Verilog module?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Verilog code showing this warning:

> encoder.v at the line ($readmemb("I:\my_data_x.txt", mem);) cannot be
>   opened for reading. Please ensure that this file is available in the
>   current working directory.

Similarly for `$readmemb("I:\my_data_y.txt", mem1);`

```
module encoder(reset,clock,out);
input  reset,clock;
output [7:0]out;
reg [7:0] x,y;
wire [7:0] m,n;
reg [7:0] mem [0:15];
reg [7:0] mem1 [0:15];
integer i=0,j=0;

initial          
    $readmemb("I:\my_data_x.txt", mem);
initial
    $readmemb("I:\my_data_y.txt", mem1);

always@(posedge clock)
    begin
        if(reset)
            begin
                x=0;
                y=0;
            end
        else 
            begin
                x=mem[i];
                i=i+1;
                y=mem1[j];
                j=j+1;
            end
    end

enc en1(m,n,out);
assign m[7:0]=x[7:0];
assign n[7:0]=y[7:0];

endmodule
```

Comment: Please add the full and exact error message to your question

Comment: encoder.v at the line ($readmemb("I:\my_data_x.txt", mem);) cannot be opened for reading. Please ensure that this file is available in the current working directory. similarly with ( $readmemb("I:\my_data_y.txt", mem1);)

Comment: Please add the message **to the question**, not to the commetn section

Comment: is there a file in the directory? I think that you need to use `\\\` for the path separator.

Comment: Sorry, getting the same result.

Comment: this just means that there is no such file in the directory you specified, or it is not readable.

Comment: Are running your tool on the same machine where your file exists?

Answer (score 0):

Beware that some GUI controlled simulators start the simulation in a totally different directory then where you started the GUI or where your source code is.

Vivado is such a simulator. I recently noticed that the path changed between version 2017 and 2018. When switching to 2018.2 the simulation starts one directory deeper then 2017. I had to add a "../" to all my paths.

This is the path I had to use for 2018.2: 
      .FILE    ("../../../../../testbench/yarp_instr.mem")

Where the Xilinx directory is alongside the testbench directory :

```
project +--
        |
        +--- xilinx_project_dir
        |
        +--- testbench
```

So first find our where your simulation runs and from that find the path to where your files are.

Comment: OP used an absolute file path